# Spring without views

Tags: spring

I am new to spring and so not sure if what I intend to do is possible.

I need to create an asynchronous webservice and a worker server (broker), both using the model & controller aspects of spring.

The webservice needs to send it's client's requests on to the broker via JMS and then instantly send a response back to the client indicating the request has been queued.

The broker is intended to remain live, processing messages from multiple webservice instances and sending back the results via an output JMS queue. The reason the broker needs to remain live is because the work to process each webservice message involves calling other webservices, some of which may be asynchronous and which may take a lot of time to process.

Additionally I do not want to spawn multiple instances of the broker as it is designed to handle multiple concurrent messages.

Is it possible to create both the webservice and broker within the same spring project, with both running in a web container such as tomcat or do I need to code them in separate projects, with perhaps the broker as a traditional standalone server rather than a web container servlet?

If so could someone point me in the right direction to creating a stay-alive broker within spring/tomcat.

I understand the webservice and JMS side of things, so do not need any help with that.